refreshToken not available after authentication from GitHub using passport-github and using GitHub's oauth method for authentication
`I am integrating GitHub in my node application. I am using GitHub oauth method for authentication. This is the code:
var GitHubStrategy = require('passport-github').Strategy;

passport.use(new GitHubStrategy({
    clientID: GITHUB_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/auth/github/callback"
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    //code
  }
));

I am getting accessToken in response, but not the refreshToken. So, what if the accessToken expires? How do I regenerate new accessToken? Do I have to again use ClientID, clientSecret to authenticate and get a new accessToken? if this so, customer has to authenticate from his/her github. That is hectic process.
I don't want the customer to authenticate after every 8 hours. Nor it is possible to educate the customer to set the expiry of accessToken to none from GitHub.
`

From Github docs on Refreshing user access tokens:

Note: User access tokens that expire are currently an optional feature and are subject to change


If you disabled expiration of user access tokens, this parameter will be omitted.

Seems like your app is not configured to expire user access tokens. A guide on how to do that can be found on that same page.
